# Find maximum of int elements using method reference

Tags: java, java-8

I'm just learning about lambda expressions and stream(). I have to write a method for a class called `ProgTetelek` which finds the maximum value of a List's elements. The limitations are: I have to avoid using `for` and `if` keywords, `add()` method and nested classes but I have to use `stream()` and method reference. Return type of the method should be Optional.
Has anybody an idea how to solve it? Solutions and good tutorials are also welcome :)

The simplest solution would be this but it does not use method reference...

```
public class Progtetelek {
    public static Optional<Integer> getMax(List<Integer> lista) {
        return lista.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparing(i -> i));
    }
}
```

The prescribed call of the method is

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lista.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 5, 8, 7, 34, 23, 11, 84, 56));
System.out.println("Legnagyobb elem: " + ProgTetelek.getMax(lista).get());
```

Comment: yes, it is... I was unobservate, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Integer::compare`:

```
public static Optional<Integer> getMax(List<Integer> lista) {
    return lista.stream()
                .max(Integer::compare);
}
```